# Android ArcGIS Javascript 2.2

Tags: android, mobile, arcgis-mobile

The website claims that touch gestures are supported for Android browsers.

I'm running 2.2 and have not been able to get touch gestures to work. What can be done to enable it?

This works for iPhone but not for Android browsers.

How would one go about making it possible to enable touch support on Android browser?

Here's a link you can try on your mobile Android browser:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/demos/mobile/mobile_simplemap.html

Comment: I'm just wondering whether this is an ArcGIS question or an Android question.  Would it get some good answers on SO?

Comment: I think(but not 100% sure) that it is an ArcGIS question that has value on this site, but @LB01 should maybe provide which touch gestures are implemented and what the expected behavior is.

Comment: Tap, Double-Tap, Drag, Press work. or at least I think they do--not really sure what the intended behavior is but stuff happens when I use those gestures on my droid with the website in the question.

Comment: What gestures aren't working?

Comment: What device have you used? We had som issues with flash not working on some devices because of the hardware in the device.

Answer (score 2):

No surprise there so far, on most 2.x devices you don't get multitouch in the webkit browser although the device can recognise more than one touch. There is an (early) [polyfill](https://github.com/Philzen/WebView-MultiTouch-Polyfill) available, which works for OpenStreetmap and GoogleMaps, but not for the link you provided :(

Update:
Thanks to Sam007's clarification the general issue cannot be related to 2.x (only). So it all narrows down to the touch event implementation of Android vs. iOs.

First thing coming to mind is that Apple introduced (proprietary, non-W3C-recognised) [Gesture Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/GestureEventClassReference/GestureEvent/GestureEvent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009353) in Safari, which to my knowledge no other browser out there implements. If ArcGis only honours those events, you will be able to solve your problem writing a "simple" touch* to gesture*-Event converter.

I'd do it myself, but i don't own any apple devices. What i would do next is to enhance your example page with a debug window and catch all the events you could think of. Find the differences between Android and iOs, and you're halfway there to make ArcGis work as expected on Android.

Comment: I don't think multi-touch is the issue. I am able to open the link on Chrome on my Xperia NEO which is ICS 4.0.4 and still the pinch zoom does not work

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on a 4.x device - good to know no bug there.